# jQuery working with Twitter bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

With bootstrap, we have about multiple div from Button 1 to button 6. Using jquery, a modal will appear with another 2 buttons, cancel and confirm.

Now, when I click confirm, modal will close and the state of the button will change. E.g Button1 changes to 'Clicked'. When I click cancel, modal will close.

The problem is this: When I click the first button and cancel, then click the second button and confirm, both buttons will change 'Clicked'

It goes the same for 4 buttons or 5 buttons.

My html

```
<!-- START OF PAID CUSTOM MODAL -->
<div id="paid-custom-modal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Fees Payment For</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    CONFIRM?
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="paid-custom-cancel btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
    <button class="paid-custom-confirm btn btn-primary">Confirm</button>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- END OF PAID CUSTOM MODAL -->
  <div class="paid-custom">BUTTON 1</div>
  <div class="paid-custom">BUTTON 2</div>
  <div class="paid-custom">BUTTON 3</div>
  <div class="paid-custom">BUTTON 4</div>
  <div class="paid-custom">BUTTON 5</div>
  <div class="paid-custom">BUTTON 6</div>
```

My jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('click', ".paid-custom", function() {
    var $this=$(this);

    $('#paid-custom-modal').modal();

    $(document).on('click', ".paid-custom-confirm", function() {
       $this.html('CLICKED');
        $('#paid-custom-modal').modal('hide');
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: click event inside a click event is generally a flaw in logic.

Comment: What do you recommend, to get a boolean from my modal buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit:

Okay I missunderstood the question, check out this code it should add your wanted behaivour, but also consider saving the state in a cookie or something otherwise every refresh would kill the state or if needed take appropriate server side handling if this buttons are meant to be only clicked once

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', ".paid-custom", function() {
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $('#paid-custom-modal').modal().find('btn-primary');
    });
    $(document).on('click', ".paid-custom-confirm", function() {
           $('.active').html('CLICKED');
            $('#paid-custom-modal').modal('hide');
        });
     $(document).on('click', ".paid-custom-cancel", function() {
           $('.active').removeClass('active');
            $('#paid-custom-modal').modal('hide');
        });

});
```

regards jan

Comment: I'm going to use the modal window to call up some text fields to update my wordpress meta posts, after confirm is clicked.

Comment: okay i missunderstood your question
look at this fork http://jsfiddle.net/TbYSd/1/
I think this is what you want to do

Comment: Exactly what was needed! Did not think of this way to solve the problem!